# how to make list inline with images and buttons?

Tags: html, css

im tying to make these two items inline with each other, each list item has an image and button, the button should be underneath each image: i.e

```
<div id="cocktails">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src ="http://bokertov.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451bc4a69e2014e8a8f894b970d-800wi" width="100px" height="100px">
            <button>Select</button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src ="http://bokertov.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451bc4a69e2014e8a8f894b970d-800wi" width="100px" height="100px">
            <button>Select</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    #cocktails ul{margin:0;padding:0}
    #cocktails ul li{list-style-type:none;display:inline;padding:0}
    #cocktails ul li img{width:150px;height:150px;display:block;float:left;padding:0 10px}
    #cocktails ul li button{display:block;float:left}
```

but the buttons are not positioned as expected the jsfiddle is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8KWGJ/

Comment: You should tell us what you've expected. Did you expect [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8KWGJ/1/)? Or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8KWGJ/2/)? My crystal ball is currently not working :(. Add a screenshot or describe what your desired result is, this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose buttons in li tags :

```
<div id="cocktails">
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src ="http://bokertov.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451bc4a69e2014e8a8f894b970d-800wi" width="100px" height="100px">
        </li>
    <li>   <button>Select</button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src ="http://bokertov.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451bc4a69e2014e8a8f894b970d-800wi" width="100px" height="100px">
     </li>
    <li>   <button>Select</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and comment css as shown:

```
#cocktails{float:left;width:419px}
#cocktails ul{margin:0;padding:0}
#cocktails ul li{list-style-type:none;display:inline;padding:0}
/*#cocktails ul li img{width:150px;height:150px;display:block;float:left;padding:0 10px}*/
 /*#cocktails ul li button{display:inline;}*/
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8KWGJ/3/

I floated the `<li>` left, instead of the button and image inside it

Answer (score 0):

Change the float from the image to the `li`.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/osuwib/1)

```
#cocktails ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#cocktails ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline;
  float: left;
  padding:0;
}
#cocktails ul li img{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  display:block;
  padding:0 10px;
}
#cocktails ul li button {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting your image to `display:block;` and the li to  `float:left;` should solve your problem.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8KWGJ/5/)

I've removed all of your CSS and implimented only the required to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8KWGJ/10/)

Change

```
#cocktails ul li{list-style-type:none;display:inline;padding:0}
#cocktails ul li img{width:150px;height:150px;display:block;float:left;padding:0 10px}
#cocktails ul li button{display:block;float:left}
```

to

```
#cocktails ul li{list-style-type:none;display:inline;padding:0;float:left;}
#cocktails ul li img{width:150px;height:150px;display:block;padding:0 10px}
#cocktails ul li button{display:block;margin:auto}
```

​
​

Answer (score 0):

Add

`clear:both;` for the buttons and images.
Also give some margin to the button.

```
#cocktails{float:left;width:419px}
#cocktails ul{margin:0;padding:0}
#cocktails ul li{list-style-type:none;display:inline;padding:0;}
#cocktails ul li img{width:150px;height:150px;display:block;float:left;padding:0 10px; clear: both;}
#cocktails ul li button{display:block;float:left;clear:both; margin-left: 60px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8KWGJ/8/

Sometimes display block does not work. So in that use clear with display:block; You can clear either left,right or both. So use clear as per the requirement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me.

```
#cocktails ul{margin:0;padding:0}
#cocktails ul li{list-style-type:none; width:150px; float:left; margin:10px;}
#cocktails ul li img{width:150px;height:150px; }
#cocktails ul li button{ margin-left:50px; width:50px}
```